# WPF SelectedItem and Scrolling

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scroll

I have a WPF DataGrid. The DataGrid is bound to an IList.  The list has many many items so the DataGrid MaxHeight is set to a predefined value and the DataGrid automatically displays a scroll bar. The selection mode and unit are set to "single full row".

The form has a button called "New" that adds an item to the list that the datagrid is bound to.After "New" is clicked, the new item should be the new selected item.  I do this via : dataGrid.SelectedItem = newItem;

This works ..but not as well as I expect it to.

I also want the dataGrid **to scroll down to the newly selected item** .. Any idea on how to do this ?

Regards,
MadSEB

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you set the SelectedItem, make sure to call [DataGrid.ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673083.aspx) with the new item.  This will make sure that the new item is visible on screen.